# PyQGIS custom script writes file as optional

Tags: pyqgis, python-script-tool

I had this problem in my custom script in PyQGIS.

I create the variable as input in this way:

```
##lista_formaciones_forestales_con_estrategia = file
```

In theory this is the correct way to write a non-optional parameter as input, but when I open my script it is writing as optional:

[image]

Is it a problem with my QGIS version? My QGIS version is 2.16.1.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be your QGIS version. I've tried with v2.14.8 and 2.18 with no luck. I faced the same issue last time and decided to validate the input parameter by myself in the script code. See highlighted lines in [this script](https://github.com/gacarrillor/QGIS-Resources/blob/master/collections/processing_scripts/processing/Export_Composers_of_Multiple_Projects.py#L16-L17) to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but the default parameter setting for both **File** and **Folder** are set to `True` in some recent versions of QGIS (not sure which ones exactly but I used QGIS 2.16.1). You can see this setting from the [GitHub script [line 503]](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py#L503):

```
def __init__(self, name='', description='', isFolder=False, optional=True, ext=None):
```

What we can do is change

```
optional=True
```

to

```
optional=False
```

You can find this script in your *processing* directory. For example, in my **QGIS 2.16.1 standalone version**, the script resides in:

```
C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.16.1/apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/parameters.py
```

Then search for `class ParameterFile(Parameter)` to see the function as shown in the link above and change the boolean value. The **File** and **Folder** parameters should now be required by default. And if you want to make it optional, use the same method as before (e.g. `##lista_formaciones_forestales_con_estrategia=optional file`).

---

*(Note: You may have to move the "parameters.py" file outside the folder, edit and save the file, then insert it back to the same folder.)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joseph, but it doesn't work me, :)

Comment: @corting - Interesting, were you able to edit the `parameters.py` file? Hopefully Germán Carrillo's solution would help ;)